# Some questions about the proof of Hartshorne Proposition I-7.4 and Theorem I-7.5

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm studying Hartshorne chapter 7, and I have a couple questions related to Commutative Algebra regarding the proof of both results (I just have some notions on localization and dimension).
First one, in Prop. 7.4.
[image]

The first question is about the proof of (b). Why do we have that $(S/\mathfrak{p_i})_{\mathfrak{p}}=0$ when $\mathfrak{p}\neq \mathfrak{p_i}$ (Note this would be equivalent to $M^{i}_{\mathfrak{p}}=M^{i-1}_{\mathfrak{p}}$). Is there any general result about that, or does it simply holds in this case? I couldn't figure out how to prove it.

[image]

The second question is at the beginning of Hilbert-Serre theorem (I also include the definition of the Hilbert function).

[image]

In this case why do we have that $\varphi_{M}=\varphi_{M'}+\varphi_{M''}$, or, $\dim(M)=\dim(M')+\dim(M'')$. Is there a result which states that $\dim(M'')=\dim(M/M')=\dim(M)-\dim(M'')$? I couldn't find it in the Com. Algebra references I usually consult.

Comment: $p_iS_p=S_p$, isn't it?

Comment: Your second question is rank-nullity in disguise!

Comment: Oh, yeah, I really forgot $(S/\mathfrak{p_i})_{\mathfrak{p}}=(S_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p_i}_{\mathfrak{p}})$.

Comment: @DanLewis3264 Oh well, I was thinking about $M$ as a $S$-module, so in that case is just a vector space, thanks!

Comment: @noname That would not only occur when $\mathfrak{p} \cap \mathfrak{p_{i}} = \emptyset$?